# Unsupported Media Type -- Spring boot

Tags: java, node.js, angular, spring-boot, postman

I am created one service in spring boot to receive and send one image, but when i am trying to send the image with postman, i am receiving the next error

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-11-08T17:01:58.015+00:00",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/reto/getImage"
}
```

The spring code is

```
@ApiOperation(value = "/getImage")
@RequestMapping(value = "getImage", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.ALL_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Resource> getImage(@RequestBody ImageOpenLayer imageOpenLayer) throws IOException {
    this.servicio.getImage(imageOpenLayer);
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("MicrosoftTeams-image.png")));
    InputStreamResource file = new InputStreamResource(in);
    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.valueOf("image/png"))
            .body(file);
}



public class ImageOpenLayer {
    private MultipartFile file;

    public MultipartFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(MultipartFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

The postman

[image: postman]

If i change the body from MultipartFile  to toher variable, the service responds ok

```
public class ImageOpenLayer {
    private String file;

    public String  getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(String file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
}
```

In postman

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use multipart/form-data, you need to change your input parameter from `@RequestBody ImageOpenLayer imageOpenLayer` to         `@RequestParam(value="file",required = false) MultipartFile file`